В юнити на сцене объекты есть, в окне игры пусто

Почему почти все объекты которые я создаю не видно на экране игры но хорошо видно на сцене,И иногда объекты появляются на экране игры тоже, но редко
В чём может быть проблема?

Проверь координаты, возможно объекты слишком далеко от камеры и не попадают в её пирамиду видимости.

Как я понимаю, белые квадраты, которых нет в Game View - это обычные 2D спрайты, которые не UI. Тогда проблема в следующем: белая рамка в Scene View на скриншоте - это не камера, а Canvas для UI. Камера находится где-то в другом месте. Так как спрайты отрисовываются не на канвасе, то их и не видно.
Решения могут быть следующие:
а) найти камеру в Scene View и располагать спрайты относительно нее. Здесь проблемой будет располагать спрайты относительно элементов UI, а также поддерживать разные разрешения экрана. Хотя, в целом, это и есть правильный подход к разработке 2D игр.
б) использовать UI Image для спрайтов. Здесь проблемой будет интеграция с различными 2D инструментами Unity. Если предполагается делать именно игру, а не условно UI, то лучше все же вариант а)
Еще можно посмотреть в сторону настройки Canvas в Camera Space или в World Space, но предполагаю, что это не совсем то, что нужно.
